# How to use external libraries in the Eclipse (Java) and Processing for Arduino

Tags: java, eclipse, arduino, processing

I was able to get functionality out of the Arduino through Eclipse following the tutorial
*[Arduino in Eclipse via Processing](http://www.benjohansen.com/arduino-in-eclipse-via-processing)*.

However, I did run into a problem; I was unable to use libraries such as the Servo library or a library for EL wire. How can I do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try Project>Properties>Build Path>Add Library>User Library. That should do the trick.